# Unable to train neural network with Neuroph framework

Tags: java, neural-network

I am trying to train a neural network to recognise letters from images. I have generated over 17000 images with letters using different fonts. The images size is 15x15 pixels.

To train the neural net I am using an input vector of 15x15 = 225 fields. Each field has 0 when the pixel is white and 1 when the pixel is black. The output vector has 36 fields and each field represent a letter or a number, for example 0 is "a", 1 is "b",... , 36 is "9". If the image represent the letter "a" then the vector is [1,0,0....0] etc.

I am using MultiLayerPerceptron with backpropagation to train the network but no matter how long I let it train, the error doesn't get smaller than 0.5 . I am using one hidden layer. I tried changing the number of hidden neurons but I still have that problem.

```
 public void Train(List<InOut> trainset, String neuralname){

            DataSet set = new DataSet(225,36);
            Random r = new Random();
            int rand;
            while (!trainset.isEmpty() && trainset.size() > 1){
                rand = r.nextInt(trainset.size()-1);
                set.addRow(trainset.get(rand).inputs,trainset.get(rand).outputs);
                trainset.remove(rand);
            }

            // Load Neural Network 
            MultiLayerPerceptron neuralnet = (MultiLayerPerceptron) MultiLayerPerceptron.load(neuralname+".nnet");

            // enable batch if using MomentumBackpropagation  
            if( neuralnet.getLearningRule() instanceof MomentumBackpropagation )
                ((MomentumBackpropagation)neuralnet.getLearningRule()).setBatchMode(true);

            MomentumBackpropagation learningRule = (MomentumBackpropagation)neuralnet.getLearningRule();// Set learningRule
            learningRule.addListener(this);

            learningRule.setMaxError(0.4);

            neuralnet.learn(set);
            neuralnet.save(neuralname+".nnet");

        }


public class InOut{
    public double inputs[];
    public double outputs[];

    public InOut(double[] inputs, double[] outputs){
        this.inputs = inputs;
        this.outputs = outputs;
    }
}
```

Comment: how many hidden neurons do you have?

Comment: I tried from 350 to 800

Comment: what's the optimization objective? cross entropy/log loss? what's the learning rate and the optimization algorithm you use (SGD, Adam etc)?

Comment: I am new to neural networks, this is my first project, so I don't how to answer those questions. The learning rate I used was 0.1. Now I am experiment with different values. I don't know what is the optimization algorithm and if I use one.